# You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Hi I'm getting the error

> You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.

when I try to execute a stored procedure.

I've seen some websites mentioning about the `bulkadmin` role, but I don't see it.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry didn't see the it coming up first time!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

- Start SQL Server Managament Studio
- Expand Security->Logins
- Locate your user, right click on it and take Properties
- Open Server Roles tab
- Make sure that `bulkadmin` is checked.
- There you can experiment with other roles if `bulkadmin` doesn't work for you.
- Click OK :)

Comment: in case some didn't find the bulkadmin role like me, you probably went to **SQL SMS - > Databases -> Security  -> Logins** , instead of **SQL SMS - > Security -> Logins** (as it applies for user to entire server not just one database)

Comment: I have the same problem. Bulkadmin server role assignment is not helped for me. Do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

Query version for Aleksandr's answer:

```
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'%userName%', @rolename = N'bulkadmin'
GO
```

Just replace `%userName%` with desired user.
Also you need to be loged in as  Sys-Admin (`sa`) or other user with `EXEC` permissions and `bulkadmin` granting permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide permission to user to fix this issue.

1. Go to MS SQL server management and connect to db.
2. In Object Explorer, go to Security and then login.
3. Look for your user and right click on it.
4. "Login Properties" popup will open
5. Click on "Server Roles" and check "bulkadmin".
   Now if you try to execute again you must not get the error.

Source: http://sforsuresh.in/asp-net-mvc-4-not-permission-use-bulk-load-statement

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue on a Sql Serverless database (Azure Synapse Analytics).

sp_addsrvrolemember is not available in this context, so I used the following to solve the issue:

```
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [username]; -- owner allows bulk operations
ALTER ROLE db_denydatawriter ADD MEMBER [username]; -- in our case we don't want this specific user to have writer
```

It doesn't feel quite right to give owner to this user. Thoughts anyone?