# You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement...with bulkadmin permission

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, bulkinsert

Bulk insert statement works in SQL Server by creating a query but when I create a stored procedure with a bulk insert it doesn't work if I call it from my ASP.Net application.

I have bulkadmin permission.

it gives me the error:

```
You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.
```

I have other stored procedures and all work fine.

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stored_procedure]
    @bulkinsert NVarChar(500)

 AS
    EXEC sp_executesql @bulkinsert
RETURN
```

Comment: Are you sure that the user that runs the app pool of your ASP.NET website has the required permissions?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002529/you-do-not-have-permission-to-use-the-bulk-load-statement

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar I have bulkadmin permission.It's not the same

Comment: @JamesBlond Yes the user has the permissions.

Comment: Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: I created a sql query and I executed it from ASp.Net by using sqlcommand class. So I didn't use a stored proceudure anymore.

```
bulkinsert = "BULK INSERT table FROM " + path + @"  WITH (firstrow=" + begin + "," + "lastrow=" + last + ",FIELDTERMINATOR ='\t', ROWTERMINATOR ='ENDOFFILE' )";
                  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(bulkinsert, conn))
                         {
                             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                         }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, Login to your SQL server using Admin Username and Password. Once in, Goto Security->Logins->Right click the Login User that you want Bulk permission for. Then select Properties->Server Roles->Check Bulk Admin as YES. It should work.
[image]

Comment: Did you do these steps even for all the Users of the SQL Manager ?

Comment: Nope, because I am not the sysadmin. I can't

Comment: Well then you might wanna track down the Admin of the SQL Manager