# Am I using SQL Server or SQL Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

I have this issue which I have asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32417776/3935156)

In all my programmatic attempts to fix the issue above, things like this are displayed in the messages box:

> Reference to database and/or server name in
>   'master..sp_addsrvrolemember' is not supported in this version of SQL
>   Server.

How do I find the version of SQL Server,I am using? It seems nothing is supported by my version.

Is the issue can be that - I am not using SQL Server somehow? I am using Microsoft Azure to host my database. Does that make you use SQL Azure? In SSMS, in the Object Explorer, at the top where it says the server, it says gonskh1ou0.database.windows.net(SQL Server 13.0.201 - Amber). Amber is my user name, and is the administrator. SQL Server 13.0.201 is not in [this list of SQL Server build numbers](https://buildnumbers.wordpress.com/sqlserver/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are using the Azure version of SQL Server, which does not support [`sp_addsrvrolemember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186320.aspx).

(Do note that that stored procedure is deprecated and you should be using [ALTER SERVER ROLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677634.aspx), which is supported at least in Azure SQL Data Warehouse's preview.)

The only way to run a full SQL Server is to create a VM and run it there yourself. The Azure version will never be the full version.

Comment: Thanks. What if I subscribed with an alternative server company such as [ixwebhosting](http://www.ixwebhosting.com) or some other company, will it be the full SQL Server? I don't really want to have to host the server myself.

Comment: I did try ALTER in another solution example I found on Stack Overflow, but it did not work

Comment: @user3935156 It certainly is not something you want to take on yourself. I don't thing Microsoft gives Azure out to anyone else, so all the other services offer actual SQL Server. They might also restrict some functionality, so not everything is possible in those either. So it depends on what you're trying to achieve in the end.

Comment: Okay cheers. I wanted to add Microsoft SQL Server to my CV, so am slightly disappointed that I am using a different adaptation of it and also it is a little harder to use google for code examples now. I chose Azure because they have a lot of mobile services that I may use later on. I have some thinking to do about what server I should use.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Microsofts implementation of SQL server, the version number and name(Amber) supplied are indeed correct. Depending on the level of Azure account you are using, this server is usually configurable.

Microsoft Azures platform contains some very nice support and I would advise consulting directly with a rep. They have always been very helpful and quick to help in regards to configuration issues, even performing the configurations for you if required.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure if this was something that can be done through Azure. I will give that a go. Although aren't all SQL Servers Microsoft? As in, SQL Server is a Microsoft product?

Comment: No SQL is a query language, Microsoft has simply adapted it for use in one of their products, But there are many forms, MYSQL,NOSQL,Hadoop SQL to name a few.

Comment: Yes but i'm talking about "SQL Server". Am I using that or SQL Azure? I don't know what version I am using either. I don't think I can get any technical support from Azure without paying a lot of money.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are using a Microsoft implementation of SQL. You'll find that most products on the Azure platform have a bit of an MS tweak to them.

Comment: I just want to be using Microsoft SQL Server. But all of the code examples that are meant to fix my problem give this error: "...is not supported in this version of SQL Server."