# bulk insert working in ssms but not working while executing from php

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to insert the data from a text file into my database. I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 17.

I'm using this query:

```
BULK INSERT db.[dbo].[mytable]
    FROM 'path/file.txt'
    WITH 
        (FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
         ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

The problem is that it's working in SQL Server Management Studio but when i'm trying to execute this php script it shows an error even though I granted the user the permission to bulk after following this:

[You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002529/you-do-not-have-permission-to-use-the-bulk-load-statement)

The error:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 4834 [code] => 4834 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement. ) )

The code i'm using

```
<?php

$serverName = "SQLEXPRESS"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"master");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}    
$query1 = "BULK INSERT db.[dbo].[mytable]
    FROM 'path/file.txt'
    WITH 
        (FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
         ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')";

$result1 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query1) or  die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true) );

?>
```

Comment: I would suggest that the user does not have the right permissions. Try `ALTER SERVER ROLE bulkadmin ADD MEMBER {Your PHP SQL Login};` (obviously replace the text in the braces (`{}`)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Account that is used by your PHP application need this permission:

```
GRANT ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS TO [server_login]
```

Your SSMS process seems run using other credentials and they have such permission.

The other reason can be if SQL Server `service account` does not have enough **permissions to read the source file**

Comment: Yes, it turns out that i'm using other credentials. The weird thing is even i'm using in PHP and SSMS windows authentication, the user in PHP script is different from SSMS. I figured that out in error.log. I think that's another issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Morsi.Hamza,  is your question answered? If so, consider to mark it as such one.